# How to remove an event listener via Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I need to remove the following event listeners with my Chrome extension, after the page loaded.

Page content:

```
<input type="password" size="15" value="" autocomplete="off"
    onkeyup="javascript:vaciar(this)"
    onkeypress="javascript:vaciar(this)"
    onkeydown="javascript:vaciar(this)" name="password"
id="contrasena" />
```

The code in my content script is:

```
var password_field = document.getElementById("contrasena");
password_field.removeAttribute("onkeypress");
password_field.removeAttribute("onkeydown");
password_field.removeAttribute("onkeyup");
password_field.onkeypress = null;
password_field.onkeydown = null;
password_field.onkeyup = null;
```

For some reason, the event listeners keep active, but when I copy and execute the code in the console it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This fails because of the [isolated context](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#execution-environment) that context scripts live in.

To affect handlers set by the page's context, you need to inject the above code into the page.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9515704/building-a-chrome-extension-inject-code-in-a-page-using-a-content-script) for a canonical explanation and examples.

Answer (score 0):

Are you putting your reset code in a body/onload function?

```
‹body onload="resetInput();"›
    ‹input type="password" size="15" value="" autocomplete="off" onkeyup="vaciar(this)" onkeypress="vaciar(this)" onkeydown="vaciar(this)" name="password" id="contrasena" /›
‹/body›
```

And declare the function

```
function resetInput(){
    var password_field = document.getElementById("contrasena");
    password_field.removeAttribute("onkeypress");
    password_field.removeAttribute("onkeydown");
    password_field.removeAttribute("onkeyup");
}
```

You don't need to unbind your event while they are inline events.